# "Полный серьёз"

Tags: фразеология

Как правильно сказать: на полном серъёзе или вполне серьёзно? Часто слушаю радио Эхо Москвы и журналист Ксения Ларина, почти в каждой передаче говорит на (полном серьёзе), серьёз - это как зайка моя. С уважением, Евгений.

Answer (score 1):

У меня такое ощущение, что "на полном серьёзе" - выражение относительно недавнего времени, лет пятьдесят максимум. При этом сначала оно употреблялось как ироничное, однако впоследствии его стали употреблять как раз "на полном серьёзе". Сравните: "две большие разницы".
Полагаю, нормативность выражения - на уровне разговорного.
//-----
Добавлю в связи с появлением новых ответов.
Лопатин даёт "серьёз" вообще без нормативных помет, Кузнецов - как разговорный.

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%F1%E5%F0%FC%E5%E7&all=x

Так что отмахнуться от существования слова просто так не получится.

Comment: Согласна с Вами.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, выражение *на полном серьезе* является фразеологизмом (устойчивым сочетанием), то есть не выходит за рамки литературной нормы. Например, согласно Викисловарю, [*на полном серьёзе* = *серьёзно*](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8C%D1%91%D0%B7).

Answer (score -1):

Появление и распространение выражений "на полном серьёзе", "короче", "прикинь", "как бы", "показывает о том", "это самое" и т.п. - это признаки-маяки деградации и "ЕГЭ-зации" социума.

Comment: Я немного дополнил свой ответ, отвечая на ваше мнение.